# How choose Trend Specification in ARDL framework?

Tags: model-selection, trend, ardl

I am running ARDL model. For the model specification I have the following Trend Specification options: 1) None, 2) Restricted constant, 3) Constant, 4) Restricted Trend and 5) Constant & Trend. How should I pick one from the list? Is there any strategy and approach to do so?